# C++ Floating Point Exception with large files

Tags: c++, error-handling, floating-point

While executing the following code with a large amount of data (roughly 2MB), I am receiving a Floating Point Exception on line 21.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int S, Q, type, seq, pos;
    int x, y, lastAnswer = 0;
    cin >> S >> Q;
    vector< vector <int> > seqList(S);

    for(int i=0; i<Q; i++){
        cin >> type >> x >> y;
        if( type == 1 ){
            seq = (x^lastAnswer) % S;
            seqList[seq].push_back(y);
            if(seq == 0) lastAnswer = 0;
        }
        else if( type == 2 ){
            seq = (x^lastAnswer) % S;
            pos = (int)(y % seqList[seq].size()); //Line 21
            lastAnswer = seqList[seq][pos];
            cout << lastAnswer << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's because size is 0. And [don't #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714) and [don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: Which compiler (and version) are you using? Naming  *"floating point"* an exception rised by an operation which doesn't involve any floating point type is really misleading.

Comment: You do know that the `^` operator is the bitwise [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator?

Answer (score 0):

```
pos = (int)(y % seqList[seq].size()); //Line 21
```

`seqList[seq].size()` is `0`. [@Lưu Vĩnh Phúc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221162/c-floating-point-exception-with-large-files#comment79405242_46221162)

With `a%b`, if `b == 0` then the behavior is not defined.  Many platforms report a *floating point* exception when an *integer* division or `%` by zero is attempted.

Re-write to to detect when `seqList[seq].size() == 0`.

Also check `S == 0` as it is used with `(x^lastAnswer) % S` [@Jeremy Friesner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221162/c-floating-point-exception-with-large-files/46221390#comment79405670_46221390)

Comment: Also it looks like the same problem could happen if S is read in as zero.